# How to get the referred diagram from an element in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a UseCase in a Usecase Diagram for which there is a reference to another composite structure diagram as shown in the figure

.[image]

[image]

Now, I want to fetch the diagram that is added to this Usecase using Enterprise Architect's Java API or from the Database. I could not find any reference to the diagram from the element in`t_object` table or any reference to usecase from the referred diagram in `t_diagram` table. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on Geert's answer: PDATA1 is used for Activity and InteractionOccurrence elements only. Any other element uses `t_xref` in such way that an entry with Name == *DefaultDiagram* is created. `Client` contains the element's GUID and `Supplier` that of the composite diagram. Moreover `t_object.NType` == 8 indicates that a composite diagram is used.

Personally I wouldn't have used the `CompositeDiagram` as I'm so much used to bypass the API (which is not always the best to do).

EA's database design can probably be best described as database scribble.

Answer (score 2):

With the API you can use [EA.Element.CompositeDiagram](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/automation/element2.html)

In the database the diagramID is stored in the field `t_object.Pdata1`, or sometimes hidden in the `t_xref` table.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The field is null for this specific object where the composite diagram is added. I will try out API way now

Comment: Geert, it's also (sometimes) t_xref. See p. 45 of my Inside book.

Comment: @qwerty_so thanks, I've added the t_xref part